# Algebra with variables having confidence intervalls

Tags: confidence-interval

In my work I have come across a situation where I need to derive values from values having confidence intervalls. I want to calculate the confidence intervals for my derived values. I am quite rusty when it comes to performing math but I seem to recall there being some strange rules for doing these kind of operations and I seem to recall it not being so easy. Perhaps someone can shed some light on it for me...

Here is my problem (I have simplified the variable names a bit):

I have 5 variables $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, and $e$ with confidence intervals $a_{lower}$, $a_{upper}$, $b_{lower}$, $b_{upper}$, $c_{lower}$, $c_{upper}$, $d_{lower}$, $d_{upper}$, $e_{lower}$, $e_{upper}$.

I then have the following derived values that I want to calculate confidence intervals for:

$$A=10^{a}$$
$$B=b$$
$$C=\frac{1}{10^c+1}$$
$$D=10^d$$
$$E=e$$
$$F=\frac{A\times C\times15\,000}{A\times C+15\,000}$$
$$G=\frac{E\times B\times 15\,000}{A\times C + 15\,000}$$
$$H=866\times\frac{D}{F}$$

Now, I am pretty sure that $A$ to $E$ is trivial, just plug the respective $?_{upper}$ and $?_{lower}$ values into the equation and be done but what about $F$ $G$ and $H$?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are positive? And most importantly, are you talking confidence intervals of a certain level ($\mathbb P(a_{low}<a<a_{upp})=\lambda$) ?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ happen to be positive yea. All of these confidence levels are at the level of 70% if that is what you mean? I got a bit unsure about the fancy P...